# Eclipse cdt plugin for array visualization

Tags: arrays, eclipse, multidimensional-array

I'm using Eclipse CDT to debug a program which contains mutlidimensional arrays. Inspecting the values of such an array is very cumbersome using the 'Display As Array' option from the variables view as suggested here: [Eclipse-C++-Debugging: see content of an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824685/eclipse-c-debugging-see-content-of-an-array).

Another possible solution which was proposed in the above discussion was using the Expressions view with the command `(*array@dimension)` but this does not seem to work for multidimensional arrays.

Now my question is if there is a plugin or a better workaround for Eclipse cdt on Ubuntu to inspect the contents of multidimensional arrays while debugging.